# @Html.DropDownList or @Html.DropdownlistFor doesn't show current value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

So I have an Html.DropDownList that I want to use on an edit page to allow users to edit the categories of different recipe ingredients.  So for example if a user wants to edit the chili recipe they are shown all the different properties for the recipe including a list of all the ingredients which they should be able to add to or delete from or edit the quantity, name and category of.  And I only want to have a drop down list to edit the category because I only want them to be able to choose from a preselected list of categories.  Here is what I have.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Recipe.RecipeIngredients.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeIngredients[i].Quantity)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeIngredients[i].IngredientName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("AvailableCategories")</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

    //// GET: /Recipe/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {           
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        EditViewModel vm = new EditViewModel();
        vm.Recipe = Db.Recipes.Find(id);
        if (vm.Recipe == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in Db.Categories)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.CategoryName, Value = item.CategoryId.ToString() });
        }
        vm.AvailableCategories = items;
        return View(vm);
    }

public class EditViewModel
{
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableCategories { get; set; }

    public EditViewModel()
    {
        AvailableCategories = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}


public class RecipeIngredient
{
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string IngredientName { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public int IsOnMenu { get; set; }
    public bool IsOnTheDamnMenu
    {
        get
        {
            return IsOnMenu == 1;
        }
        set
        {
            IsOnMenu = value ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }

    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the property of `Recipe` that shows the selected category?

Comment: Recipe has a a list of ingredients.  Each ingredient has a category which has an id and a categoryname

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the definition of `RecipeIngredient` class?

Comment: sorry- yes added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just found that I can pass more properties into this.  So something like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Recipe.RecipeIngredients[i].CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.AvailableCategories, "Value", "Text", Model.Recipe.RecipeIngredients[i].CategoryId),  "-Select-")
```

Shows the correct category now.